# Count occurances of multiple text strings

Tags: powerquery, m

I am looking to tell if a text is present in a text string, however I am looking to test multiple texts. For example trying to find if dog OR lazy are present in

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and the lazy dog doesn't notice"

Tried 
let
    String = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and the lazy dog doesn't notice,",
    Count = List.Count(Text.Split(String,"dog","lazy"))-1
in
    Count

from this article [Is there a simple way to count occurences of one text string within another text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268075/is-there-a-simple-way-to-count-occurences-of-one-text-string-within-another-text)

If dog OR lazy are present in

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and the lazy dog doesn't notice"

Would expect yes or 1

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text.Split does not take two arguments

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-split

Try instead

```
Count = List.Count(Text.Split(String,"dog")) + List.Count(Text.Split(String,"lazy"))-2
```